# Loading JCombobox with data selected using a WHERE clause

Tags: java, sql, arrays, swing, jdbc

Im trying to load to combobox by comparing datain a table and data from myframe but evreytime my code runs I get this error message:- java.lang.NullPointerException, I also tried using a vector. please help:this is a code from my database class

```
    public ArrayList allocateStaffcombobox(Allocation aloc) throws SQLException
{
    ArrayList<Allocation> vec = new ArrayList<Allocation>();
    String sql = "select * from staffsubalocation where SubCode='"+aloc.getSubjCode()+"'";

    ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    while (result.next())
    {

        String staffNo = result.getString("StaffNo");

        String subcode=result.getString("SubCode");
        System.out.println(staffNo+" "+ subcode);
        vec.add(new Allocation(staffNo,subcode));
    }

    return vec;

}
```

this is code from my java class:

```
     public  void loadStaffCombo()
    {
        try
        {
            DatabaseManager db = new DatabaseManager();
            ArrayList<Allocation> sub=db.allocateStaffcombobox(null);
            Staffcombobox.removeAllItems();
           // String firsIndex = " ";
            for(int x = 0; x< sub.size(); x++)
            {
                Staffcombobox.addItem( sub.get(x).getStaffNo());
            }

        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(ViewSubjectsJInternalFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: can you post the error stacktrace?

Comment: You are explicitly passing `null` in the statement `ArrayList<Allocation> sub = db.allocateStaffcombobox(null);` in `loadStaffCombo` method which definitely gives you a `NullPointerException`

Comment: How can i fix this(by not passing null in that statement

Answer (score 1):

You are passing null as the input to:

```
ArrayList<Allocation> sub=db.allocateStaffcombobox(null);
```

And you try to dereference that null at:

```
String sql = "select * from staffsubalocation where SubCode='"+aloc.getSubjCode()+"'";
```

Whenever you try to invoke a method on a null object you will get a NullPointerException